# Expose garbage collector in a Node.js app with StrongLoop support

Tags: node.js, strongloop

We are trying to call the garbage collector into a Node.js application.

In a regular Node.js app, this is quite simple, you only need to run your service with a param:

```
node -expose-gc script.js
```

And simply call *gc* into your code when you want to call the garbage collector:

```
Global.gc();
```

But since we are moving to StrongLoop, and we run the app with the *slc* tool.

The question is: How can i specify the *-expose-gc* parameter when running the app with *slc*? Using  the next command, the gc() call fails:

```
slc -expose-gc run script.js 

(and when you exect Global.gc() you get...)
TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'gc'
```

It seems that the run flag is ignored

Comment: Is `slc` just a script? It may not be passing command line arguments.

Comment: AFAIK this is a binary file that wraps the node binary

Comment: if you verify that it is (`where slc`) ... you'll probably need to contact StrongLoop. May I ask why you're trying to call the garbage collector manually?

Comment: We are experiencing memory leaks problems in a production scenario, and we are trying to fix the issue quickly. Thanks for your interest!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`slc run` doesn't pass its arguments to node, so don't use it, just use `node`. You won't lose anything, there isn't any special stuff `slc run` does.

`slc run` was conceived as a wrapper around common Node.js tools (node, npm, node-inspector, etc.) to simplify interactions for people, so they wouldn't have to learn about multiple tools. It turns out, folks are comfortable with multiple tools, and it sometimes just makes things harder.

(I'm the slc/strong-cli maintainer, btw.)

Comment: Thanks Sam, i thought that it was vital for my app to run :)